# Error in calling Worksheet_FollowHyperlink() from another module

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

Worksheet_FollowHyperlink() is in Module2 and Module3 and I am trying to call it from Sheet00.

Sheet00

```
Sub data_hyplink()
Dim ws As Worksheet
i = 1

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "main" Then
        Sheets("main").Cells(i, 2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheet00.Cells(i, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:="", TextToDisplay:=""
        Sheets("main").Cells(i, 3).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheet00.Cells(i, 3), Address:="", SubAddress:="", TextToDisplay:=""
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub

Sub display_sheets(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Module2.Worksheet_FollowHyperlink
    Call Module3.Worksheet_FollowHyperlink
End Sub
```

Sample content from Module2 and Module3 (their only difference is the address)

```
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

If Target.Range.Address = "$B$2" Then
    a_asb_mw.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    a_asb_mw.Activate

ElseIf Target.Range.Address = "$B$3" Then
    a_asb_wn.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    a_asb_wn.Activate

...

EndIf
```

Whenever the hyperlinked cell is clicked, it should open the hidden sheets however, I cannot seem to make it work. Perhaps it is the parameter I am trying to pass `Sub zz_display(ByVal Target As Range)` which is incorrect. I tried `ByVal Target As Hyperlink` but it did not work too.

What am I missing? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` requires a Hyperlink argument passed to it, which you aren't supplying.

Comment: I suggest redesigning your flow. `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` is a reserved event used at the worksheet level and will trigger whenever a hyperlink is clicked inside of a sheet with the code added in the worksheet object. Therefore, move this code inside the module for `Sheet00` (and change it to a private module) and it should work as needed. You could also create your own your procedure if you want (it's harder so I don't know why you would want to), but if you do, use a different name.

Comment: Hi All, thank you for the reply. I tried placing the two Worksheet_FollowHyperlink inside Sheet00 but I get the error that the name is ambiguous (because it appears twice in Sheet00). This is why I opted to create a module so that I could call them without having the error.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff you could merge both modules into a single one if the only difference is the address, then as Scott suggested, place the code instead of in a module, under Sheet00, then it should work as expected...

Comment: Hi, All. Thanks for the reply and suggestion. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put this macro in Sheet00, and it will accomplish what you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Sheets("a_asb_wm").Visible = True
        Sheets("a_asb_wm").Activate
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        Sheets("a_asb_wn").Visible = True
        Sheets("a_asb_wn").Activate
    End If

End Sub
```